# How to insert into a table when UUID is used to generate a column ID?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I created a table "Centres" with `CentreID` defined as UUID:

```
CREATE TABLE `Centres` (
    `CentreID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `CentreName` VARCHAR(45),
    `Address1` VARCHAR(45),
    `Address2` VARCHAR(45), 
    `City` VARCHAR(45),
    CONSTRAINT `PK_Centres` PRIMARY KEY (`CentreID`)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO Centres VALUES(UUID(), 'my centre', 'address1', NULL, 'London');
```

It created `CentreID` as `ccdd2852-b9de-11ec-a791-f4ee08b2b85a`.

Now I'd like to create another table "OpeningTime", with `CentreID` as one of its columns.

```
CREATE TABLE `OpeningTime` (
    `OpeningTimeID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `Centres_CentreID` VARCHAR(36)
);
```

When inserting data, should I just do:

```
INSERT INTO OpeningTime VALUES(UUID(), 'ccdd2852-b9de-11ec-a791-f4ee08b2b85a');
```

Or is there a better way to insert the UUID without the long VARCHAR?

Comment: IN my opinion that's not an appropriate use of uuid.

Comment: @P.Salmon could you please elaborate?

Comment: Also worth reading is: [Mysql 8.0: UUID support](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-uuid-support/)  (an article from Dec 2016)

Comment: Hi, you dont have a UUID type in your database ?
like :     `CentreID` UUID NOT NULL UNIQUE,

Comment: @GweltazNiquel I defined the datatype as `VARCHAR(36)`, not `UUID`

Comment: UUID is useful to merge rows from distributed/different databases across servers. Does this resonates with what you have to do? If not, the better solution here is to use an integer and set it to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so that you don't even need to remember it when you're doing `INSERT` operations.

Comment: @lemon I wanted to use UUID cause it's non-predictable

Comment: 'I wanted to use UUID cause it's non-predictable' - well I'm sure you have done your research see my answer for an alternate insert method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or is there a better way to insert the UUID without the long VARCHAR, ANOTHER way would be insert..select..where centre name is known and unique.

```
INSERT INTO OpeningTime 
select UUID(), centres.centreid
from centres
where name = 'bromsgrove';
```